# docker-compose: group_add works with group id but not with group name

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a container that needs to run other containers at some point.

I use `group_add` to add my container's user to the host's `docker` user group.

This works fine if I set the group id, but not with the group name. Documentation says it should work with both https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#group_add . Any ideas on this issue ?

Here is a simplified version of my docker-compose file :

```
version: '2.1'
services:
    my-worker:
        image: workers/data-handler:1.0.2
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        group_add:
            - 994 #docker group id
        command: run
```

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that the `docker` group inside the image does not have the same group id as the host. Check the group id of docker inside the container:

```
$ getent group docker | cut -d: -f3
```

When you use `group_add: docker` it looks up the docker group inside the container, so your user won't have the right permissions. Since you are mounting the docker.sock file, it will use the host permissions (including ids), so you need to provide the correct id.

I have not got this to work in my environment in a workable fashion and resorted to a shell script instead of `docker-compose` since it worked in my use case and I am not using the extra functionality `docker-compose` provides.

```
#!/bin/bash

DOCKER_GROUP=$(getent group docker | cut -d: -f3)
docker run \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    --group-add $DOCKER_GROUP \
    workers/data-handler:1.0.2
```

Comment: The `docker` group gid inside the container should be irrelevant according to the `docker run` documentation (unless there's a bug in a corner case when  `--group-add=name` conflicts with an existing `name` inside the container and it silently ignores the command).  The official Docker documentation shows that `--group-add=docker` will lookup the GID on the host, and map that thru to the same GID inside the container and grant the executing container user membership in that group regardless of whether the host group is specified by name or explicit GID.

Comment: @mtalexan could you point me to the documentation? I didn't see that level of detail on the [`docker run` reference page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#additional-groups). Maybe this has been functionality has been added in the last 2 and half years, and I will try to see if I can reproduce with latest docker I have installed.